# Finding two integers that multiply to 20. Can I make this code more "pythonic"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did this code that finds two integers in a said list (in this case [2,4,5,1,6,40,-1]) that multiply to twenty. I got a little stuck in the beginning, but adding a function to it solved my problems. I showed this code to a friend of mine who's a programmer and he said I could make this code more "pythonic", but I have no clue how.

Here's the code:

```
num_list = [2,4,5,1,6,40,-1]

def get_mult_num(given_list):
    for i in given_list:
        for j in range(i+1, len(given_list)): #for j not to be == i and to be in the list
            mult_two_numbers = i * j
            if mult_two_numbers == 20:
                return i,j

print(get_mult_num(num_list))
```

Comment: I don't think this is what you want: `for i in given_list: for j in range(i+1, len(given_list)): ...` use `print i,j` to see the results. `i` is not the index of `given_list` it is an element of it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't necessarily think it is 'unpythonic', you are using standard Python idioms to loop over your data and produce a single result or `None`. The term *Pythonic* is nebulous, a subject marred in ["I know it when I see it"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) parameters.

Not that you produced a *correct* implementation. While `i` loops over `given_numbers`, `j` loops over an integer from `i + 2` through to `len(given_numbers)`, mixing values from `given_list` with indices? For your sample input, you are taking `j`  from the half-open ranges [4, 7), [6, 7), [7, 7) (empty), [3, 7), [8, 7) (empty), [42, 7) (empty) and [1, 7), respectively. That it produces the correct answer *at all* is luck, not due to correctness; if you give your function the list `[2, 10]`, it'll not find a solution! You want to loop over `given_numbers` *again*, limited with slicing, or generate indices starting at the current index of `i`, but then your outer loop needs to add a `enumerate()` call too:

```
for ii, i in enumerate(given_numbers):
    for j in given_numbers[ii + 1:]:
        # ...
```

or

```
for ii, i in enumerate(given_numbers):
    for jj in range(ii + 1, len(given_numbers)):
        j = given_numbers[jj]
        # ...
```

All this is not nearly as efficient as it can be; the Python standard library offers you the tools to generate your `i, j` pairs without a nested `for` loop or slicing or other forms of filtering.

Your double loop should generate [*combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of the integer inputs, so use the [`itertools.combinations()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate unique `i, j` pairs:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_mult_num(given_list):
    return [(i, j) for i, j in combinations(given_list, 2) if i * j == 20]
```

This assumes there can be zero or more such solutions, not just a single solution.

If you only ever need the first result or `None`, you can use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
def get_mult_num(given_list):
    multiplies_to_20 = (
        (i, j) for i, j in combinations(given_list, 2)
        if i * j == 20)
    return next(multiplies_to_20, None)
```

Next, rather than produce all possible combinations, you may want to *invert* the problem. If you turn `given_list` into a set, you can trivially check if the target number 20 can be divided cleanly without remainder by any of your given numbers and where the result of the division is larger *and* is also an integer in the set of numbers. That gives you an answer in linear time.

You can further limit the search by dividing with numbers smaller than the square root of the target value, because you won't find a larger value to match in your input numbers (given a number `n` and it's square root `s`, by definition `s * (s + 1)` is going to be larger than `n`).

If we add an argument for the target number to the function and make it a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators), then you get:

```
def gen_factors_for(target, numbers):
    possible_j = set(numbers)
    limit = abs(target) ** 0.5
    for i in numbers:
        if abs(i) < limit and target % i == 0:
            j = target // i
            if j in possible_j and abs(j) > abs(i):
                yield i, j
```

This approach is a *lot* faster than testing all permutations, especially if you need to find all possible factors. Note that I made both functions generators here to even out the comparisons:

```
>>> import random, operator
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> def gen_factors_for_division(target, numbers):
...     possible_j = set(numbers)
...     limit = abs(target) ** 0.5
...     for i in numbers:
...         if abs(i) < limit and target % i == 0:
...             j = target // i
...             if j in possible_j and abs(j) > abs(i):
...                 yield i, j
...
>>> def gen_factors_for_combinations(target, given_list):
...     return ((i, j) for i, j in combinations(given_list, 2) if i * j == target)
...
>>> numbers = [random.randint(-10000, 10000) for _ in range(100)]
>>> targets = [operator.mul(*random.sample(set(numbers), 2)) for _ in range(5)]
>>> targets += [t + random.randint(1, 100) for t in targets]  # add likely-to-be-unsolvable numbers
>>> for (label, t) in (('first match:', 'next({}, None)'), ('all matches:', 'list({})')):
...     print(label)
...     for f in (gen_factors_for_division, gen_factors_for_combinations):
...         test = t.format('f(t, n)')
...         timer = Timer(
...             f"[{test} for t in ts]",
...             'from __main__ import targets as ts, numbers as n, f')
...         count, total = timer.autorange()
...         print(f"{f.__name__:>30}: {total / count * 1000:8.3f}ms")
...
first match:
      gen_factors_for_division:    0.219ms
  gen_factors_for_combinations:    4.664ms
all matches:
      gen_factors_for_division:    0.259ms
  gen_factors_for_combinations:    3.326ms
```

Note that I generate 10 different random targets, to try to avoid a lucky best-case-scenario hit for either approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help and very clear explanation. I'll sure adapt it.

Comment: What if the list was a 100 range, how could I adapt my code using combinations to return the values that multiply to said target value?

Comment: @MarcelloFabrizio: that goes well beyond being 'pythonic' now, now we are writing math puzzle solutions. :-) I've updated my answer to suggest an approach.

Comment: I edited my question with the new code. I implemented the combinations you explained.

Comment: @MarcelloFabrizio: that's really not needed; we are trying to build a repository of questions and answers for future visitors, your question was better suited towards that goal without the addition. I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(i,j) for i in num_list for j in num_list if i<j and i*j==20]
```

Comment: This does more than twice the amount of work needed. You loop N ** 2 times over a list of numbers of length N, but there are only [*(N choose 2)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) combinations. That's 49 iterations in your case where only 21 are needed, less than half. You take the full square with N along both sides, but you only need to consider one half of that square and ignore the diagonal, so (N * (N - 1)) // 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: a) the condition `if i<j ` excludes one of the triangles b) you can't ignore the diagonal unless you're sure it doesn't contain `sqrt(20)`, unless you want to write special-case for when `sqrt(N)` is an integer, which would be silly. So in general it should be ` if i<=j`, you have to include the diagonal

Comment: @smci: the assumption here is that the input list of integers is unique and that you must pick two distinct values from it. That means that there is no `i == j` case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok but the question never actually stated that the numbers have to be distinct. Colloquially we might interpret it that way, but it doesn't prohibit it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using list-comprehension. This also helps to find multiple such-pairs if they exist in the given list.

```
num_list = [2,4,5,1,6,40,-1]

mult_num = [(num_list[i],num_list[j]) for i in range(len(num_list)) for j in range(i+1, len(num_list)) if num_list[i]*num_list[j] == 20]
print mult_num
```

**Output:**

```
[(4, 5)]
```

Comment: Note: your implementation has the same error as the code in the question; try this with `num_list = [2, 10]`, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks for checking my answer and pointing out the error. I have fixed it and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it, which uses [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def get_mult_num(given_list):
    return [
        item1, item2
        for i, item1 in enumerate(given_list)
        for item2 in given_list[:i]
        if item1*item2 == 20
    ]
```

I think your friend may be hinting towards using [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) when it makes the code cleaner (sometimes it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

You could make it more pythonic by using itertools.combinations, instead of nested loops, to find all pairs of numbers. Not always, but often iterating over indices as in `for i in range(len(L)):` is less pythonic than directly iterating over values as in `for v in L:`.

Python also allows you to make your function into a generator via the `yield` keyword so that instead of just returning the first pair that multiplies to 20, you get every pair that does by iterating over the function call.

```
import itertools

def factors(x, numbers):
    """ Generate all pairs in list of numbers that multiply to x.
    """
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(numbers, 2):
        if a * b == x:
            yield (a, b)

numbers = [2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 40, -1]
for pair in factors(20, numbers):
    print(pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. It reverses the approach a little bit, in that it searches in `num_list` for the required pair partner that the iteration value `val` would multiply to 20 with. This makes the code easier and needs no imports, even if it's not the most efficient way.

```
for val in num_list:    
    if 20 / val in num_list:
        print(val, int(20/val))
```